# a reddit-php-sdk method not outputting anything

Tags: php, reddit

I'm trying to learn reddit code and using this https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk

There's a method in this library `$reddit->getUser()` which outputs `null` always. Everything else seems to be working though.

```
include_once("jcleblanc-reddit-php-sdk-4a4cc32/reddit.php");
$reddit = new reddit("my-username", "my-password");
$userData = $reddit->getUser();
var_dump($userData);
```

outputs `null`.

```
$response = $reddit->getListing("all", 5);
var_dump($response);
```

outputs what's expected just fine. Then what could be going wrong with `$reddit->getUser()`?

Answer (score 0):

this is Jonathan LeBlanc, I created that library.  I'm running tests right now and I don't seem to be seeing the same issues.  This is the code I'm running with the library:

```
<?php
require_once("reddit.php");

$reddit = new reddit("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
var_dump($reddit->getUser());
?>
```

When running that, I am seeing my user data object coming through.  Are you still experiencing this issue?

- Jon

Comment: What should the redirect uri be in the config?

Comment: The application location where you want the user redirected to after they are forwarded to Reddit to accept the permissions of the application.

Comment: Any way I can get it to login without user interaction?

I want to be able to scan posts and reply to certain ones, as a bot?