# reddit-php-sdk method not outputting anything

Tags: php, reddit

Re-asking this question, as it was never solved: 
[a reddit-php-sdk method not outputting anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810166/a-reddit-php-sdk-method-not-outputting-anything?rq=1)

SDK: https://github.com/jcleblanc/reddit-php-sdk

When running Jon's  example:

```
<?php
require_once("reddit.php");

$reddit = new reddit("USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
var_dump($reddit->getUser());
?>
```

I get the following:

```
object(stdClass)[2]
public 'error' => int 403
```

If I remove the username and password (which is how it seems to be presented in the documentation), It brings me to reddit to authorize my app, which I accept, then it sends me back to my php page, which just says

```
null
```

---

Here's what I'm really trying to do, I had no luck with either example [Reddit api sdk doing nothing, returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26198159/reddit-api-sdk-doing-nothing-returns-null)

Comment: I am also having this exact problem using this code.  I will answer if I figure anything out.  Have you figured out a solution yet?

Comment: Nope, I've tried all that I could. I'm considering looking for other solutions. There is another library, https://github.com/hnrysmth/reddit-api-client, but it seems a lot more complicated to set up (though I haven't looked to far into it). Might be able to do it without the API using cURL, though I'm not positive it has everything we'd need, and can't do all the same things, and would be slower. Guzzle also might be worth researching, but I haven't gotten that deep yet. Was waiting a bit hoping someone would answer.

Comment: If you just need to scan pages, I had luck with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ . But submitting forms needs something more.

Comment: Hey, I tried using cURL to submit links like I need to and it's actually not bad. Reddit's API documentation tells you exacly what pages you need to query and what to send them, and cURL only takes a few lines to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Pull this fork from git hub.

unzip and setup config

https://github.com/markdavison/reddit-php-sdk/commit/2c2eac7f2202720e3fbb80b1ef48c87a6a213ff6

I just figured this out after a while ;-)